# How can I patch only selected patches via AWS SSM patch manager or Run command.Only selected kb or patch for both windows and linux server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, patch, aws-ssm

How can I patch only selected patches via AWS SSM patch manager or Run command.Only selected kb or patch for both windows and linux server?

If we have 10 kb article missing but I want only 4 to patch and reject all other patches.I want to do with Run command.

Is it possible via AwsWindowsUpdatepatch ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InstallOverrideList` parameter in `AWS-RunPatchBaseline` or `AWS-RunPatchBaselineAssociation`

You can use the InstallOverrideList parameter when you want to override the patches specified by the current default patch baseline in Patch Manager, a capability of AWS Systems Manager. This topic provides examples that show how to use this parameter to achieve the following:

- Apply different sets of patches to a target group of managed nodes.
- Apply these patch sets on different frequencies. Use the same patch
- baseline for both operations.

As per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/override-list-scenario.html